# How to convert a "true-color" image to an "one-color" image, with PHP?

Tags: php, image, colors, gd

> I have read all related questions on *Stack Overflow*, which has a *group-of-word*: *black-and-white* or *monochrome*. These posts are discussed about one of two common problems: *gray-scale* or *black-and-white*. 
>  I do **not** want my output image in *black-color* only; but, I want more. I want my output picture in *one-color*, which is given by a variable, for instance: `$MyColor = #336699;`, `$MyColor = #3366CC;` ... 
>  So, my question is **not** duplicated with any existed question.

---

First, I have an original image, which is a *true-color* image. It is saved in [JPEG](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JPEG) format:

[image: *#1*. The original image.]

This original picture has: *16 777 216* colors.

---

Then, I could convert it into a *gray-scale* image, after running this simple script:

```
<?php 

$source_file = "1.JPG";

$im = ImageCreateFromJpeg($source_file); 

$imgw = imagesx($im);
$imgh = imagesy($im);

for ($i=0; $i<$imgw; $i++)
{
        for ($j=0; $j<$imgh; $j++)
        {

                // Get the RGB value for current pixel

                $rgb = ImageColorAt($im, $i, $j); 

                // Extract each value for: R, G, B

                $rr = ($rgb >> 16) & 0xFF;
                $gg = ($rgb >> 8) & 0xFF;
                $bb = $rgb & 0xFF;

                // Get the value from the RGB value

                $g = round(($rr + $gg + $bb) / 3);

                // Gray-scale values have: R=G=B=G

                $val = imagecolorallocate($im, $g, $g, $g);

                // Set the gray value

                imagesetpixel ($im, $i, $j, $val);
        }
}

header('Content-type: image/jpeg');
imagejpeg($im);

?>
```

And, below is result:

[image: *#2*. The gray-scale image.]

This gray-scale picture has: *256* colors.

---

Now, I want to convert it into a **real** *one-color* image:

[image: *#3*. The one-color image.]

This one-color picture has: *1* color.

In this case, `$MyColor = #000000;`.

---

Can you show me: *How to convert a true-color image to an one-color image, with PHP*?

Comment: If there is any problem with my question, please post below. I will read it; then, I will improve it.

Comment: Hint for you to search for: "dithering"

Comment: It's also voted to be closed. Mostly because you did no research yourself and you simply ask for tutorial

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just two lines of code will handle the grey scale conversion and reducing the image to only ***two colours*** (because a one-colour image is a blank canvas), with dithering:

```
$img = imagecreatefromjpeg('./38519049.jpg');

imagefilter($img, IMG_FILTER_GRAYSCALE); // convert to grey scale.
imagetruecolortopalette($img, true, 2); // 'true' for dithering, '2' for number of colours.

header('Content-type: image/jpeg');
imagejpeg($img);
```

Result:

[image]